# Recognize facial features directly from captured webcam images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am not sure if I can ask such a question in this forum,

so if I shouldn't, please say so kindly!

I have one month to do the following:

**1**. Capture some peoples' photos using a webcam.

**2**. Calculate the actual locations of their facial features; e.g. corner of the mouth.

**3**. Generate the actual position of each landmark in x and y distance in mm from the
tip of their nose.

**4**. Calculate the actual physical dimensions of their face, if they hold up a standard size credit card and I know the webcam resolution (since I know the size of a standard credit card).

I am familiar with `C++` and I have just started to learn `OpenCV` very intensively, using this text book:

*Learning OpenCV  ( Gary Bradski and Adrian Kaehler )*

Is this the way to go? Learning OpenCV for such projects?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yea, opencv
2. [flandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/)
3. no idea what you mean
4. this step probably has to go *before* step 3

(about the book : great resource, unfortunately the code is horribly outdated. they stopped using the c-api like 5 years ago ( and you probably should not use it anymore ) )

Comment: Thanks for your help and comments. So that's why I get so many people telling me to stop using this book! About number 3 I mean: The tip of the nose being the center and origin of the coordinates on the images.

Comment: oh, if the face is only slightly tilted, the nose is *not* the center of the image. once you got flandmark running, you'll see. they got  a seperate mark for center and nosetip.

Comment: btw, almost any of the code samples from the book [lives here in a modern version](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/cpp) . you probably got them already on your disk